# Overwrite duplicate property key loaded by apache common PropertyConfiguration

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have been looking for a property for apache commons property configuration that can overwrite duplicate keys present in a property file instead of appending the properties and treating like a list, but cannot find any such property. Is there a workaround for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Apache commons property configuration will load only the first key value pair that is found in the properties file.As of my knowledge it does not offer any property you are looking for.This behaviour is seen because the PropertiesConfigurations calls resolveContainerStore(key) method. The default implementation goes something like this

```
protected Object resolveContainerStore(String key)
    {
        Object value = getProperty(key);
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value instanceof Collection)
            {
                Collection collection = (Collection) value;
                value = collection.isEmpty() ? null : collection.iterator().next();
            }
            else if (value.getClass().isArray() && Array.getLength(value) > 0)
            {
                value = Array.get(value, 0);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

In this implementation it returns the first value found for the given key from a list of values i.e value = Array.get(value, 0);

You can override the default implementation if you want that the properties should be overwritten so that the last loaded property is returned. Here is my implementation of the above function.

```
@Override        
protected Object resolveContainerStore(String key) {
                Object value = getProperty(key);
                if (value != null) {
                    if (value instanceof Collection) {
                        Collection collection = (Collection) value;
                        Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
                        value = null;
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            value = iterator.next();
                        }
                    } else if (value.getClass().isArray() && Array.getLength(value) > 0) {
                        value = Array.get(value, Array.getLength(value) - 1);
                    }
                }
                return value;
            }
```